# DataContractSerializer and List(Of Exception)

Tags: .net, xml, exception, serialization

How can I serialize a list of Exception objects (also including derived exceptions, eg. FileNotFoundException) with the DataContractSerializer?

I always get an error about the serializer not knowing the types in the list so i devised a workaround.

It looked something like this:

```
Dim XmlSerializer As New DataContractSerializer( _
    ExceptionsList.GetType(), ExceptionsList.Select(Function(i) i.GetType))
XmlSerializer.WriteObject(Stream, List)
```

This works. I just add all the different exception types to the list of known types and it works. But on deserialization I am stuck. The problem is i dont know the types of exceptions stored in the file beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're SOL. The serializer needs to know the types that might be in the input.

You could try using the [`NetDataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.netdatacontractserializer.aspx). That outputs type metadata in addition to the data being serialized.

Comment: This works thanks, I wonder why you can't just do this with the regular serializer.

Comment: Because the regular serializer just serializes to XML that is interoperable. You need to tell it what types are possible, otherwise it can't deserialize. The `NetDataContractSerializer` gets around this by adding type metadata to the XML. This is also why you can't use it to communicate to a non-.NET service or client.

Comment: I just found out that the NetDataContractSerializer cannot serialize in medium trust (i am on shared hosting, if i try to serialize i get security exception), so i guess  i'll have to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

You might try unboxing the Exceptions going into the serializer to System.Exception. I don't if this would have any real impact, but at least the type passing through might register as something standard.

(shot in the dark)